# AWS Elastic Beanstalk .ebestensions/nginx/nginx.conf not overriding AWS' default nginx.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have an AWS environment and I'm trying to override the nginx.conf that is used.

According to [their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html), this can be done by including your own file at `.ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf`

> To override Elastic Beanstalk's default nginx configuration completely, include a configuration in your source bundle at .ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf

I've done that to no avail. I've tried creating an entirely new application environment to ensure it's not due to the instance not fully restarting, but the original `nginx.conf` is still being used. I have one other `.ebextensions/` configuration file, and it is creating a file as expected.

Any clues as to why my `nginx.conf` isn't taking? Any details I could provide that might grant some insight? I searched for errors within `eb-activity.log` but did not see any. It did say that it `inflated` the `.ebextensions/nginx/` directory and `created` the `.ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf` file in the logs where it does so for the rest of the files / directories in your source bundle. Nowhere does it indicate that it tried to use my nginx.conf, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation I was looking at was specifically for the java environment. The method works for several other environments, but the node environment startup process is different and ignores that file. I imagine it's because the server directive is within `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`, rather than `nginx.conf`.

However, you can still override the `nginx.conf` by instead using an .ebextension config to create the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as I found from the reply in [this AWS Forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=717865%F2%AF%90%A9)